# URL not getting inserted in SQLite3 database

Tags: cocoa-touch, sqlite, ipad, ios

I'm trying to insert the url links in the SQLite3 database but its crashing
does any one have any idea ... y its happening ?

if i statically trying to insert any url, it works but dynamically when I get urls of navigated web pages.... they do not insert.... 
please suggest me how to make it work. I'm using SDK 3.2

this is my insert function:

```
-(BOOL)insertImageToDB:(UIImage *)screenImage forURL:(NSString *)webURL
{
    BOOL retValue=NO;
    sqlite3 *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *insert_statement = nil;

    //NSString *localURL = webURL;

    NSString *localURL = @"https://www.google.com/";

    if (sqlite3_open([[self sqlitePath] UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "insert into Web_Image (Screen_Image, url) Values (?,?)";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &insert_statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(screenImage, 0);
            if(data != nil)
            {
                sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_statement, 1, [data bytes], [data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            }
            else 
            {
                sqlite3_bind_blob(insert_statement, 1, nil, -1 , SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            }
            sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [localURL UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            //sqlite3_bind_text(insert_statement, 2, [webURL UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            if(SQLITE_DONE == sqlite3_step(insert_statement)){
                retValue=YES;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_reset(insert_statement);
        sqlite3_finalize(insert_statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

where, screenImage: is the current web page screenshot.
       webURL: is the url of the current web page.

Comment: More information about the crash, please? The line it crashes on would be a great start.

Comment: One thought: `sqlite3_step` should be run in a loop until it returns `SQLITE_DONE`. You may have to call it more than once.

Answer (score 1):

For static WebPageUrl

```
NSString *localURL = @"https://www.google.com/";
localURL =[localURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

For Dynamic WebPageUrl

```
NSURL * url = Any web page url.....
NSString *localURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
localURL =[localURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Now You can insert this formatted Local url in database as string.